# how to disable iGnss in android system

Tags: android-service

I'm debugging Gnss service in ANDROID 9 system on my platform.  i dont compile android/hardware/interfaces/gnss,so this service should be not started. But when the system is booting up, i see this log:

> init: Received control message 'interface_start' for
>   'android.hardware.gnss@1.1::IGnss/default' from pid: 1065
>   (/system/bin/hwservicemanager) init: Could not find service hosting
>   interface android.hardware.gnss@1.1::IGnss/default init: Received
>   control message 'interface_start' for
>   'android.hardware.gnss@1.0::IGnss/default' from pid: 1065
>   (/system/bin/hwservicemanager) init: Could not find service hosting
>   interface android.hardware.gnss@1.0::IGnss/default

why gnss service was started, not like my expected is not started.
Anyone can help disable this service, or show me where gnss was initialized. i dont want start this gnss when system booting up.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is not that gnss service is started. You see the error message because gnss service is not started and the framework is expecting some service which could serve gnss interface. To get rid of this error message you need to provide a service ( hal implementation) that serves gnss interface. The default implementation should do this job unless there is another implementation that overrides default one but doesn't serve 1.0 and 1.1 interface.

I have an implementation that overrides the default one but provides only 1.0 interface so the error message I see is only for 1.1 interface. I am trying to adapt my implementation to support 1.1 interface also. Hope that'll solve the problem.

Since your question was asked long back, please share if you already have a solution.

Comment: How do you add the default implementation to an AOSP project?